# Postgis how to add a vertex to a linestring at intersection with a point?

Tags: postgis

I'm using postgis 2.0 and I want to add a vertex to a linestring (pipes) at intersection position with a point (startpoint of waterlateral). 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

ST_Snap may work for you. The PostGIS Help doc snaps a Polyline and Polygon. You want to snap a Polyline and Point, which hopefully, adds the Point location to the Polyline segment.